# ESD capacitor simulation for human body model

Tags: esd

I have designed an ESD suppression circuit with the help of ESD capacitor using LTspice. In the circuit, 15kV input pulse is given to ESD human body model and the resistor, capacitor used near the source are as per the standards.Capacitor C2 value is calculated as per the theory. Now my question is, 
1. i have used a switch before C1. Is this switch needed?
2. Output at C2 is same as C1. C2 does not influence the circuit. 
What should i do to get the correct output?
Plz refer the image for details.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Wires in LTSpice are ideal, they do not in any way shape or form influence the circuit. So two capacitors in parallel are ideally connected and the position (close or half a mile away) doesn't change anything. I do not fully understand what your result is and what you are trying to achieve (expectation), maybe you could elaborate a bit on that.

Comment: Hi. My work is to protect the device (IC) from ESD by adding external capacitor near the exposed terminal. For which, i have simulated HBM and in the output i have placed a ESD protection capacitor C2. Input given was 6kV. Now, i want to supress the ESD spike from entering into the exposed pin of the IC. So, at C2 this 6kV should be suppressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read this [article from Texas Instruments](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/industrial_interface/f/142/t/359524?Electrostatic-discharge-Human-Body-Model-versus-IEC61000-4-2) ?

To test your ESD protection properly you need to create the correct pulse. This can be done using a circuit like this:

[image]
 ESD generator models according to HBM (left) and IEC 61000-4-2 (right)

As you can see the idea behind the Human Body ESD model is that a capacitor is charged to a certain voltage and that charged capacitor is then discharged (through a defined series resistor) through the device under test.

The discharge of the capacitor causes a current to flow and a voltage to develop across your DUT. You need to check if that current and voltage do not exceed the limits of what your DUT (the protection inside it) can handle. At least, that's how I simulate my ESD protections!

Your circuit will only briefly charge the capacitors, it does not simulate the high voltage discharge at all.

Comment: Hi, Thank u so much for your reply. My work is to protect the device from ESD by adding external capacitor near the exposed terminal. With reference to the model u have posted, i simulated the circuit. For this, in the place of DUT i placed the external ESD protection capacitor and given the input voltage of 6kV. Now the question is, 1. As per HBM standard, the resistor and capacitor values are 1500ohm and 100pF. But in the TI model they have given 1M and 100pF. Are these values correct? 2. After simulating this model (reference to TI) im getting output voltage across the capacitor as 40mV.

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: Regarding the TI model with 1 M ohm: are you sure that 1 Mohm is used for the **discharging** of the capacitor? Because I think it is used for **charging** the 100 pF. An ESD discharge with 1 Mohm in series basically **isn't a proper ESD pulse** as the current will be limited to a very safe (harmless) level. The discharge resistor should really be 1.5 kohm or in that order of magnitude.

Comment: Sure, you can get only 40 mV across the capacitor **BUT** that's is when you simulate with an **ideal** capacitor. You should add the capacitor's parasitics also like series resistance (ESR) and series inductance. Then you will get much more than 40 mV!

Comment: 1M ohm is protective resistor. This value is given in the model. but how will we get the output if im using this big resistor in the beginning?

Comment: That 1 M ohm resistor is connected to the **high voltage** supply, it protects the **user** when (s)he accidently touches the high voltage contact on the switch. Also directly (without a series resistor) charging the 100 pF capacitor is bad for the capacitor. In both cases the 1 Mohm resistor limits the charging current to a safe level. The energy for the ESD pulse is stored **in the capacitor**. Charging the capacitor takes less than 1 ms even with 1 Mohm because the capacitor is only 100 pF. But because the voltage is high, that still gives a nasty ESD pulse.

Comment: but if im using 1M ohm resistor, output voltage at the protection capacitor is 700uV. I doubt its correctness.

Comment: Instead if i use 100ohm, im getting 3.6V as output.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, in your simulation you need to make sure that the 100 pF capacitor is fully charged to the high voltage. Only then flip the switch to make the ESD pulse. *Instead if i use 100ohm* 100 ohm for what? Be clear. Also if you say *I doubt its correctness* that doesn't mean anything. You put something in the simulator then it will give you the correct answer. If you think the answer should be something else then **prove it**. Do a hand calculation, show what the answer should be. Then find the error in the schematic in the simulator.